# Evaluate a constant expression in matlab

Tags: function, matlab

I am currently writing a script that takes a function and interval from the user and then evaluates the integral using the trapezoid method. The script also evaluates the error. To do so, I need to use the second derivative of the function entered. In the case where the second derivative is a constant or 0, I get the Too many input arguments error. Here is a small section of the code to illustrate where the error happens:

```
%integrate x^2 from 0 to 5
syms x
func = x^2;
deriv = diff(func,x,2);
func = matlabFunction(func);
deriv = matlabFunction(deriv);
deriv(0:0.01:5); %<- error since deriv = 2, needed to compute the error on the trapezoid method.
```

Is there a way for matlab to evaluate the vector 0:0.01:5 and return a vector of the same size with the value "2" for each value passed? Whether the  function deriv is a constant or not is unknown and depends on what the user enters.

Comment: I think I found one possible solution, but I'd like people to confirm that this indeed won't cause unintended consequences when the function is not a constant. If I were to do ```deriv = matlabFunction(deriv,'Vars',x)```, would that work?

Comment: If you are using symbolic math, you should use symbolic math to compute the integral. https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/vpaintegral.html

Comment: The symbolic math is just to derive the function, then most of the computation is done substituting values. If I were to use symbolic math, a lot of subs will be required, which will increase the computation time. In some part of the code, each new iteration seems to take exponentially longer to compute, with one iteration taking almost no time, the next a few seconds and the one after that a few minutes (don't know why, but isolated it to the subs function). Converting them to numerical seems to be the best thing to do, since some requires thousands of iterations.

Comment: One more point I forgot to mention, the value of the integral itself is not the main purpose of the script, it's to specifically apply the trapezoid method. It's for a course i'm taking about numerical methods. So using the built in integral functions defeats the point

Comment: `subs` taking a long time to compute is strange, but it also seems unrelated to your question, as you don't talk about computation time there at all, nor use `subs`. I still think you need to skip `matlabFunction`. If you don't want to use `vpaintegral` because you want to manually do the numerical integration, then get your sampled function with `double(subs(deriv,0:0.01:5))`. This takes a small fraction of a second with your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the sounds of it, a logical structure should suffice to address the problem. The challenge in developing it, however, stems from having to juggle between three(3) data types (`double`, `sym`, and `char`). I couldn't find a crisper way, but this should handle the issue (see explanation below it for insight):

```
syms x
func = x^2;
deriv = diff(func,x,2);
IN = *input vector*; %User-defined input vector.
N = length(IN); %Get length of input vector.
algebra = char(deriv); %Convert algebraic expression "deriv" to character array.
[num,status] = num2str(algebra); %Check to see if "deriv" is algebraically equivalent to a constant.
if status == 1 %If so
    deriv = num*ones(N,1) %Extract its value and copy it along a vector of the same length as the input
else %Run your code essentially.
    func = matlabFunction(func);
    deriv = matlabFunction(deriv);
    deriv(0:0.01:5);
end
```

**NOTE:** From here on out, `x = sym('x')`

Say the user defines the expression `f = 3*x^3`, then, calling `diff` on it as `der = diff(f,x)` should output `der=9*x^2`. Since this is a non-zero derivative, then you would proceed with the trapezoidal rule algorithm. However, say `f = 2`, the result of calling the diff function of this new `f` would be `der = 0`. **BEWARE**: when `diff` differentiates an expression that results in a constant, the output is considered at `sym` object. In this example `0` is a `sym` object, not a `double`. To convert it to a `double`, one could think to cast it so as `c = double(der)`. The problem is, that `double()` does not have the functionality to handle the cases when `der` is still an algebraic expression (i.e. if `der = 3*x`, then `double(der)` returns an error). The function `char()`, however, can handle that. In fact, it should be able to convert any `sym` expression to a `char` array. This then permits the use of the `str2num()` function, which has an optional parameter to determine if string-to-double (or  char-to-double) conversion is possible or not. The syntax is: `[num,status] = str2num(char(der))`. If `der =3*x`, then `char(der) = '3*x'`, `num = []`, and `status = 0`. However, for the constant derivative case, say `der = 3`, then `char(der) = '3'`, then `num = 3`, and `status = 1`;

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply, I'll give your method a try, but I found something that seems to work. I don't understand what it does exactly, but it seems to do what I want (I don't know if there are side effects in some fringe cases though, perhaps you do?). If I replace in my code ```deriv = matlabFunction(deriv)``` to ```deriv = matlabFunction(deriv,'Vars',x)```, I can now evaluate the constant function by doing ```deriv(0:0.01:5); ```. Would that cause any problem or would this be a valid workaround?

Comment: I just ran your code and the modification proposed in your last comment. On my end, `deriv` is returned as a `1by1 double`, meaning it is not a row vector, rather, a scalar. If you need a row vector of 2's, then on my end at least this does not appear to solve the problem. To be honest, I'm a stranger to `matlabFunction()` so i cannot provide as much insight as I wish I could.

Comment: Thank you so much, you've been a lot of help. I didn't realize that the function returned a 1x1 double, but it's still better than an error. I will work my way around with this in mind. I was thinking about creating a vector of the same size as the input, filled with one's and then multiply each element in the vector by that double. In the case where matlabFunction() is not a constant, it will return a vector and multiplying that vector by the 1's vector will yield the same vector and in the case where it is a constant, it will create a new constant vector. Would that work?

Comment: It will in principle. I do that in the answer that I posted above. Look for the line `deriv = num*ones(N,1)`. The way I have it set up is so that `num` is the scalar value of the constant derivative case.

Answer (score 1):

@J.A. Ferrand: I cannot comment below your answer (too low reputation), but the solution you provided has an obvious mistake. Instead of `num2str` in line 7 of your code we should use `str2num`.

Below I provide my own approach to the problem based on J.A. Ferrand's solution.

Converting constant algebraic expressions into function handles is problematic, since in that case `matlabFunction` cannot "quess" what is the number of function variables and what are their names. However, in case you are dealing with functions of a certain number of input variables (for example: one) below is an "improved" version of `matlabFunction`.

```
function fh = matlabFunctionImproved(symExp)

% This is an improved version of matlabFunction function,
% that circumvents an "inconvenient" behaviour of the original function
% in case of constant argument.
% Remark: This function works properly only for single-valued functions.
    
charExp = char(symExp)  % Convert algebraic expression to character array.
[num,status] = str2num(charExp) ;  % Check to see if symExp is algebraically equivalent to a constant.

  if status == 1 %If so
    fh = @(x) num * ones(size(x)) ; %Extract its value and copy it along a vector of the same length as the input
  else % Run your code essentially.
    fh = matlabFunction(symExp);
  end

end
```

Presented code can be modified in case of working with functions of two or more variables...